# Custom EditTextPreference and setOnPreferenceChangeListener not called

Tags: android

My listener is not getting called for some reason? This is what I have:

In Preference file I have a custom EditTextPreference:

```
    <com.xxx.yyy.preference.PreferenceEditTextDialog
        android:layout="@layout/preference_edit"
        android:title="@string/title"
        android:summary="@string/summary"
        android:defaultValue=""
        android:dialogTitle="@string/dialogTitle"
        android:key="mypref"/>
```

I extend my class:

```
public class PreferenceEditTextDialog extends EditTextPreference {
```

Launching my Activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, PrefsActivity.class));
```

Definition:

```
public class PrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements   
OnPreferenceClickListener, OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
```

In here I register my setOnPreferenceChangeListener (which is not called).

However changing my Preference file from:

```
<com.xxx.yyy.preference.PreferenceEditTextDialog
```

to default:

```
<EditTextPreference
```

it all works. Could someone help me to find the problem, somehow the listener is not propagated properly using my custom Preference.

Thanks!

@Sam Here my listener definition:

```
    myfield = (EditTextPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(KEY_PREFERENCE);
    myfield.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            Boolean valid = true;
        if(!validate(newValue.toString())) {
               valid = false;
            }
            return valid;
        }
    });
```

Comment: My first guess is that the problem is in the listener. Post it in your question.

Comment: I updated my post, but I kept all my code the same except changing the  Preference file back to <EditTextPreference and my listener definition stayed the same.

Comment: Are you overriding `setOnPreferenceChangeListener()` or anything like it in your custom class?

Comment: Not in my PreferenceEditTextDialog. In my PrefsActivity I have:    @Override public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference pref) {  AND  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {

Comment: I must admit, with the information provided I'm as baffled as you.

Comment: Found a solution, see update. I guess I did not post all the code:-) I checked out the original code from Android's EditTextPreference and found the hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution, in my custom EditTextPreference I added a call to callChangeListener(value):

```
@Override
public void onBindDialogView(View view) {       
edittext = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext.setText(PreferenceManager.
        getDefaultSharedPreferences(view.getContext()).
        getString(getKey(), ""));       

ok_button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
ok_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String value = edittext.getText().toString();
        if(callChangeListener(value)) {
            Editor editor = getEditor();
            editor.putString(getKey(), value);
            editor.commit();
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    }
});
```