# EditTextPreference.setText(value) not updating as expected

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity, edittextpreference

I'm trying to prevent the user from entering an empty string into an `EditTextPreference` (in the example, `catName`). I use a `OnPreferenceChangeListener` to detect when a change is made to the `EditTextPreference`, and if there is a change and the string is blank, I use the `EditTextPreference.setText()` command to reset to the old value. However, the new value doesn't show up properly if I reopen the `EditTextPreference` in the GUI (the string is blank), and if I go back into the main app, I can verify that a blank value is being saved to the preferences.

I've verified that the if statement executes as expected, and that my parameter keeping track of the old name (`oldCatName`) is updating as expected. I can even log the `catName.getText()` value right before the `setOnPreferenceChangeListener` finishes execution and I always see the value I expect (the new value set by the user, and when they enter a blank value, it properly resets to the old value). I'm not sure why setting the value to the `EditTextPreference` isn't saving the value to the preferences file or updating the GUI.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private String oldCatName;
    private EditTextPreference catName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

        catName = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("cat_name");
        oldCatName = catName.getText();

        catName.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newVal) {
                final String value = (String) newVal;
                if (value.equals("")) {
                    catName.setText(oldCatName);                
                    Log.e("new value", catName.getText());
                }
                else
                    oldCatName = value;
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!
-Michael

Edit: A clarification. The logic in the if statement is executing correctly. The string value of the `EditTextPreference` is even updating correctly. However, the value in the GUI if the user taps on the `EditTextPreference` again does not correctly update, and the value in the app's shared preferences does not update correctly. It stays blank.

Comment: if (value.equals("") || value.equals(null))

Comment: I gave it a try, but unfortunately no luck. I'm fairly confident that the issue isn't in the if statement executing unexpectedly, but rather with my method using to edit the value.

Comment: what is `newVal`? is it `EditText`?

Comment: Yes, and if I run `Log.v()` on `value` from `final String value = (String) newVal;`, it always shows the new string.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501099/custom-edittextpreference-and-setonpreferencechangelistener-not-called

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found a solution by doing the following:

- I used a `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` instead of a `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener`. The `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener` looks for when the user changes a preference through the settings menu, and behaves before the change is committed to the preference data. The `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` listens for changes to the actual preference data, not changes in the GUI, so it happens a little later. I noticed that in my first attempt, I could run `setText()` immediately followed by `getText()` on my `EditTextPreference` object, and the `getText()` value wouldn't match what I had just set the `setText()` value to. I'm not sure why this happens, but waiting for the changes to actually commit before trying to run `setText()` led to the correct response. Maybe it was a timing issue?
- I run `setPreferenceScreen(null)` and `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings)` after updating the value in the `EditTextPreference`. If I didn't do this, sometimes when the user would click on the `EditTextPreference` again, the value in the field would appear blank even though the value in the settings file wasn't. This forces the settings page to, more or less, refresh itself.

The working code is below:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private String oldCatName;
    private EditTextPreference catName;
    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        createListener();
        catName = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("cat_name");
        oldCatName = catName.getText();
    }

    private void createListener() {
        listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
                String value = sharedPreferences.getString("cat_name", "NULL");
                if (value.equals("")) {
                    catName.setText(oldCatName);
                    setPreferenceScreen(null);
                    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
                } else {
                    oldCatName = value;
                }
            }
        };
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about the `getString("cat_name", "NULL");` - what are you trying to achieve ? Notice also that when `createListener` runs `oldCatName` is null. Bottom line - do you need `setPreferenceScreen(null);` ? I am using the same approach and do not think so but I have to be sure

Comment: Mind that if one does more things after addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings) (eg add listeners, setup ui aspects etc), she should do them after this call as well (or move them into a method)

Answer (score 1):

~9 yrs late, Hope this helps some one else. 
I too faced similar issue. It can be done simply by returning false. As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener#onPreferenceChange(androidx.preference.Preference,java.lang.Object)) states returning true will update the value and you want to ignore changes.

```
catName.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newVal) {
            final String value = (String) newVal;
            if (value.equals("")) {
                catName.setText(oldCatName);                
                Log.e("new value", catName.getText());
                return false ; // <----------------------------------
            }
            else
                oldCatName = value;
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you're not able to find the `setText` method in your preference object (`catName` in the above example), check if you defined the preference as an `EditTextPreference` specifically (contrary to just `Preference`). I made this mistake and it cost 2 hours of my life...